# How can I check for a new line in string in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check for a new line in a string?

Does python3.x have anything similar to java's regular operation where direct `if (x=='*\n')` would have worked?

Comment: I was hoping for solutions to checking for _any_ kind of newline not just unix style.

Comment: note: [there are multiple Unicode characters that may be recognized as newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

Comment: @ThorSummoner: Python uses universal newline mode by default i.e., platform-specific newline such as `'\r\n'`  is translated to `'\n'` on input and in reverse `'\n'` is translated to `os.linesep` on output. If you don't care about Unicode newlines; `'\n'` is all you need in most cases.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you just want to check if a newline (`\n`) is present, you can just use Python's `in` operator to check if it's in a string:

```
>>> "\n" in "hello\ngoodbye"
True
```

... or as part of an `if` statement:

```
if "\n" in foo:
    print "There's a newline in variable foo"
```

You don't need to use regular expressions in this case.

Comment: as a complement if you want to know if the string ends with '\n' you should do if "\n" == foo[-1]

Answer (score 18):

Yes, like this:

```
if '\n' in mystring:
    ...
```

(Python does have regular expressions, but they're overkill in this case.)

Answer (score 10):

See:

https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines

> A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Windows convention '\r\n', and the old Macintosh convention '\r'. See PEP 278 and PEP 3116, as well as str.splitlines() for an additional use.

I hate to be the one to split hairs over this (pun intended), but this suggests that a sufficient test would be:

```
if '\n' in mystring or '\r' in mystring:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this, using str methods?

```py
if len(mystring.splitlines()) > 1:
    print("found line breaks!")
```